# How to map an image on a texture?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I'm very new to Blender and I'm just learning textures. When I take an image like this and place it on a plane:

[image]

and render it I get a visible line in the final image like this:

[image]

I'm so new I'm not sure what words to use to search here in Blender Stack Exchange to find if someone has already asked and got the answer to this problem I'm having.

I know I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi, your object is a plane? I would in edit mode and top view, press U->Project From View Bounds. If that fixes it I'll put together an answer. If not, could you post more information like what your object's geometry looks like, how it's UV unwrapped, or even better, a .blend file (use [BlendExchange](http://www.blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com))

Comment: What you need is called UV unwrapping. read: http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/unwrapping.html?highlight=unwrap

Comment: If you wish to obtain a perfectly mapped image on a plane, try the "import images as planes" add-on (bundled but not enabled by default): when enabled, in the file > import menu you'll find that option. You can then use that mapped plane to understand how the image is mapped, learning how to do it yourself, which is always best...

Comment: Dalek Maker - thanks for that suggestion but that is what I did. I found that if I don't go to edit mode and press U->Project From View Bounds that it will only render as black plane. I do appreciate you taking the time to answer. In the future I now know that I should have included that information in my question.

Comment: m.ardito - I am not aware of the "import images as planes" add-on so I'll look into that and see if it works. As I said I am about 3 weeks into my playing with Blender so much is unknown to me. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: cegaton - I do have a basic understanding about the UV unwrapping but only with 3 weeks of playing leaves me with much that is unknown. I'm working on texture/materials for my first focus area. I appreciate that you took the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Tab into edit mode, and in top mode, press <kbd>U</kbd> -> Project From View (Bounds).

[image]

This should unwrap your plane properly so that the image maps across it correctly.

[image]

If your image isn't square, you'll need to do some extra scaling (of the plane) in the UV Image Editor to get it to match correctly, or you'll get stretching on the plane.

Then just apply the texture in the material.

[image]

Comment: Dalek Maker - I'm not sure that I follow what you're suggesting. My assumption is I have to match the image size with the size of the plane. However, I was thinking that might be a problem but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I was trying to figure out where I do the plane scaling to the image scaling. The problem I had was that the image is in pixels and the plane has size but I'm not sure of the units that the values represent.

Comment: I tried m.ardito's suggestion of enabling 'import images as planes' and this seemed to work for me. I've got some other images that I was having trouble with so I'll try this on those images too.

Comment: Just updated to try to make it a bit more clear. Import Images as Planes is an excellent addon, so if you're just trying to import image, that's probably the best option. But doing it manually is a good way to learn.

Comment: Thanks Dalek Maker for the clarification. I will learn to do this manually but I'm a little overwhelmed by all that is going on in this software.

Comment: Yeah, it's a lot to get your head around, but it's definitely worth learning.

Comment: Dalek Maker - thanks for the short tutorial. The new topic in it to me is the  UV Image Editor. I've never looked at it before. Maybe that is what I was missing. Anyway, thanks again for taking the time to introduce a noob to image unwrapping. It's something I will be looking into.